# Random eos account name with cleos

Tags: cleos, account-name, account-creation

Is there a way to generate a random EOS accountname or map to the public key? I remember at the beginning of the ICO, Block.one assigned a random generated name to your EOS public key. Is there a feature like that in cleos?

Answer (score 1):

There's no feature like that in Cleos. 
You have write your own function for generating random accountnames and afterwards you need to verify that the generated accountname is available.